# Is there any way to get how many time Retry attempted requests before sucess?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am implementing the usage of the `Retry` module from the `requests` library in my Django project. I want to know that using `Retry` how many failed attempts have been made before success attempt?

This is how I implemented the code:

```
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry
from urllib3.exceptions import MaxRetryError
from requests.exceptions import RetryError

url = "https://api.github.com/user/repos?page=1" 

retry_strategy = Retry(
    total=3,
    status_forcelist=[429, 401, 500, 502, 503, 504],
    allowed_methods=["GET"],
    backoff_factor=1
)
print(retry_strategy)
adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry_strategy)
http = requests.Session()
http.mount("https://", adapter)
http.mount("http://", adapter)

try:
  response = http.get(url)
except MaxRetryError and RetryError:
  print("Still no success after 4 attempts - skipping")
```

Comment: `.history` attribute of `Retry` object?

Comment: Unrelated but `except MaxRetryError and RetryError` should be `except (MaxRetryError, RetryError)`

Comment: @matszwecja Is there any docs on it I can refer to? It is giving me `()` output.  I have used in `exception` block like this `print(retry_strategy.history)`